# Modx api runsnippet запуск сниппета в файле?

Tags: api, modx, сниппет

На сайте есть форма, при отправке Ajax отправляет на php данные на проверку. Пытаюсь вызвать сниппет phpthumbof

**php**

```
<?php
// Подключаем modx api
define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index.php';

....

$options = "w=100&h=100&zc=1&far=C&q=95";
$image = $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . '://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/user_upload/'.$fileName; // тут все правильно
$userImage = $modx->runSnippet('phpthumbof', array('input' => $image, 'options' => $options)); // комментируя эту строку никаких ошибок не появляется

echo json_encode(['error' => '<img src="'.$userImage.'" alt="">'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
exit;
....
```

При сабмите появляется ошибка

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":500,"statusText":"error"}
```

Comment: `phpthumbof` использует локальные файлы для работы, а вы ему на вход подаете ссылку на изображение

Comment: @Tunker подскажите как исправить? Пытался ему скормить '/user_upload'.$fileName; - тоже не сработало

Comment: @Tunker использую ту же команду **runSnippet** только не в отдельном файле, а в сниппете, то есть сниппет вызываю в сниппете и там все работает, и ссылка на изображение, которую я скармливаю **phpthumbof**, абсолютная. А также с загружаемыми изображениями с помощью компонента **Migx** phpthumbof тоже отлично работает

Comment: Есть в логах что? modx и сервера, попробуйте написать тестовый сниппет просто возвращающий 1 к примеру, и вызвать его через свой ajax чтобы убедиться что у вас инициализируется класс modx. И приведите какой файл вы передаете phpthumbof, `$image = $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] ....` - чему равна переменная, так получается что она у вас делает ссылку на изображение типа https://site.ru/user_upload/test.jpg а phpthumbof требуется указать на локальный файл, типа `/public_html/user_upload/test.jpg`, попробуйте из менеджера файлов скопируйте путь к любой картинке локальной и вставьте его в свой вызов

Comment: @Tunker у меня есть другие формы, работающие через Ajax. Все нормально. Проблема конкретно в вызове команды **runSnippet**. $Modx инициализируются, проверял. Да $image = абсолютная ссылка на изображение от https:// до .jpg|png... Также пробовал указать локальный путь /home/..../public_html......test.jpg та же ошибка

Comment: Посмотрите все-таки логи, по ходу возвращается 500 ошибка, в логах самого сервера может есть что-то или модх?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решено!**

Установить **phpthumbsup** и запускать его через команду **runSnippet**